# Why Index is not used with subquery

Tags: sql, firebird

This takes 0.001 seconds to execute and it uses index seek

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ID IN (1008,1122)
```

Now I have a stored procedure U_VIP which returns the same ID as example one (1008,1122), and it takes only 0.001 second to execute

```
SELECT ID FROM U_VIP    //returns (1008,1122)
```

Now when I combine them, it takes around half-a-second to execute and index is not used

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM U_VIP)
```

I've simplified the example above, in actual application the performance is impacted by much higher magnitude. How to force Firebird to use index in this case?

**Using Firebird 2.1

** EDIT **

Base on Mark's answer, use JOIN does improve the execution time because it is now doing index seek.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.* 
FROM CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN U_VIP ON U_VIP.ID = CUSTOMER.ID
```

This is great, however, it introduces another problem for me which I'll try to explain in the following example.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.* 
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE (:AREAID = 0 OR ID IN (SELECT ID FROM U_VIP(:AREAID)))
```

Using where clause, I can conditionally apply the filter base on whether :AREAID is supplied by the user. How do I achieve the same when I replace the where clause with a join?

Something like:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.* 
FROM CUSTOMER
{IF :AREAID > 0 THEN}
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID FROM U_VIP(:AREAID)) VIP ON VIP.ID = CUSTOMER.ID
{END IF}
```

Which of course, Firebird dislikes the part with braces =/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `IN`, you need to use `EXISTS` or an `INNER JOIN`. I am not entirely sure about the details, but I believe in your query the `CUSTOMER` table is fully read, evaluating the result of the subquery for every row (maybe even executing the subquery for every row). As the optimizer doesn't know the number of results of the subquery in advance, it can't create an optimization like it can if you use a fixed number of literal values like in your first query.

Try changing your query to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM U_VIP WHERE U_VIP.ID = CUSTOMER.ID)
```

Or:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.* 
FROM CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN U_VIP ON U_VIP.ID = CUSTOMER.ID
```

Or (changing the order sometimes can lead to better performance):

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.* 
FROM U_VIP
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.ID = U_VIP.ID
```

In general I would expect those queries to perform better than the query with `IN`.

**Edit in response to update**

Based on your updated question I can think of multiple solutions, I am not entirely sure on their performance though.

- Use separate queries for `:AREAID` is 0 and `:AREAID` is not 0
- Use a stored procedure or [`EXECUTE BLOCK`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-execblock) with an `EXECUTE STATEMENT` with a dynamically built statement (variant of the previous)
- Make the stored procedure U_VIP return all customers if `:AREAID` is 0
- Use an additional `JOIN` condition `OR :AREAID = 0`; this might not yield results if U_VIP returns nothing for 0 (and might not perform *)
- Use a `LEFT JOIN` and add `WHERE U_VIP.ID IS NOT NULL OR :AREAID = 0` (might not perform *)
- Use a `UNION` of the 'normal' query and a second query on `CUSTOMER` with `WHERE :AREAID = 0` (might not perform *)

For **(*)** see the ['Smart logic'](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic) anti-pattern

For the dynamically built query you can think of something like:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK (INPUTCONDITION INTEGER = ?)
    RETURNS (ID INTEGER)
AS
    DECLARE VARIABLE QUERY VARCHAR(6400);
BEGIN
    QUERY = 'SELECT a.ID FROM SORT_TEST a';
    IF (INPUTCONDITION <> 0) then
        QUERY = QUERY || ' WHERE a.ID = ' || INPUTCONDITION;
    FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT QUERY INTO :ID
    DO
        SUSPEND;
END
```

In this example the value 0 for `INPUTCONDITION` will generate a query without `WHERE`-clause, and for other inputs a query with a `WHERE`-clause. Doing it like this is prone to SQL injection if the parameter is a `(VAR)CHAR` or `BLOB`, so be careful. You could also consider two branches where one uses [`EXECUTE STATEMENT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-forexec) with parameters and the other without.

Instead of `EXECUTE BLOCK`, you can also use a selectable procedure like you already use for `U_VIP`; `EXECUTE BLOCK` is essentially a stored procedure that isn't stored in the database.

See also ['Myth: dynamic SQL is slow'](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/myth-directory/dynamic-sql-is-slow)

Comment: @Kagawa I am not sure if I understand you, but I guess using a `UNION` (a normal one, not `UNION ALL`!) of the query joining on `U_VIP` and an additional select on `CUSTOMER` and using the condition `CUSTOMER.ID = :INPUTCUSTID` on the second query would do the trick. This will get you the U_VIP and the specific customer.

Comment: @Kagawa If that is the actual problem, you might want to update your question to add that piece of info :)

Comment: Question updated with details of the problem. My comment is removed due to it was badly constructed (was in a hurry - sorry).

Comment: @Kagawa Updated my post with some ideas on how to achieve what you want

Comment: I think I'll just go with the UNION method, it does slow down a little performing a UNION on two SELECT statements, but in general it performs better than the conditional WHERE IN solution. This is especially true when U_VIP is returning larger result set. Thanks!