# Why does Firebird 2.5.5 and higher not use index on WHERE IN subquery?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

My issue started with an update statement that was incredibly basic and properly indexed, but didn't make proper use of the indexing and has started bogging in production as the record counts increase. I have seen old posts that state using an `IN` with a subquery in old Firebird versions was not optimized at all, but I am using 2.5.5, then upgraded to 2.5.7 just to make sure, and the problem still seems to be happening.

My understanding is that "this was resolved in later versions of Firebird" on articles dates ages before 2.5 even, but that is not what I am seeing and I do not know why.

I was able to resolve the performance issue for my UPDATE statement in my next app build with a MERGE statement, but I am now perplexed as to why this case doesn't work as I expect and if there is something I can do to fix it, or if it is a limitation of the engine that I should avoid.

Take this schema (I've done both dialect 1 and 3 - this is 3 though):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST 
(
  TESTID                INTEGER         NOT NULL,
  TESTNAME              VARCHAR(    50)  COLLATE NONE,
  DETAILID              INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE DETAIL 
(
  DETAILID                INTEGER         NOT NULL,
  DETAILNAME              VARCHAR(    50)  COLLATE NONE
);

CREATE ASC INDEX I_TEST_DETAILID ON TEST (DETAILID);
```

I created 10k records in each table and integer field numbered 1 to 10k.  I then try a super simple SELECT.  Please keep in mind, my original statement was an UPDATE statement that was the same from the FROM down - I do understand in a SELECT I can do a JOIN and whatnot for better performance, but according to everything I've read, this is supposed to work correctly now, and yet I cannot get the PLAN results I expect:

```
SELECT
  T.*
FROM
  TEST T
WHERE
  T.DETAILID IN (SELECT D.DETAILID FROM DETAIL D WHERE D.DETAILID BETWEEN 1 AND 100)
```

This results in:

```
PLAN (D INDEX (PK_DETAIL))
PLAN (T NATURAL)
```

The PLAN for T is always natural, so it reads the entire 10k records every single time. If I run just the subquery part alone, it correctly reads only the 100 records and uses the DETAIL primary key.

I read, in many places including here, to use EXISTS instead.  So, I try that:

```
SELECT
  T.*
FROM
  TEST T
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DETAIL D WHERE (D.DETAILID = T.DETAILID) AND (D.DETAILID BETWEEN 1 AND 100))
```

Same exact results. T is PLAN Natural and 10k records are read.

So, I am at a complete loss. I have tried everything I can think of, including different dialects, different 2.5 versions, and different indexing (foreign keys, etc), and making sure the selectivity is properly calculated. I have scoured the Firebird bug tracker trying to see if this is an open issue, but all the ones I find are infinitely more complex and don't seem to apply to this simple example. If this is supposed to work, I do not understand how, nor why it isn't working for me.

And, although I did get my UPDATE improved by going to a merge (it behaves as expected in both plan and record reads), the command is more complicated and not necessarily the first thing you think to do when want to do such a simple operation. Not to mention, I was hoping to fix a production system without changing the SQL in my code, but I have a feeling that isn't going to be possible after these findings.

**UPDATES:**
In order to clarify some of the questions in the comments.  My original query that was causing the issue was the equivalent of this:

```
UPDATE  
  TEST T
SET
  T.TESTNAME = "SomeValue"
WHERE
  T.DETAILID IN (SELECT D.DETAILID FROM DETAIL D WHERE D.DETAILID BETWEEN 1 AND 100)
```

I only converted the query for the question to a SELECT for ease of reproducing and testing.  UPDATE and DELETE statements can't use joins.  The performance of a JOIN in a SELECT does indeed fix the problem, but the subquery is my option in UPDATE and DELETE.

Other answers:

- I only put 2.5.5 as that is the version that I was working with.  I do not know if it worked in previous versions and did not mean to imply it STOPPED working in 2.5.5.
- Removing the WHERE on the subquery doesn't change the PLAN.
- All IDs are unique and simply liner 1 to 10k, so the BETWEEN 1 AND 100 gives exactly 100 rows.
- My reference as to why I thought EXISTS should work: [Why Index is not used with subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715521/why-index-is-not-used-with-subquery)
- My reference about this being fixed in newer versions (note, site seems to be down right now): http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq37/

Since the last reference isn't pulling up, this is what it says:

> Why is my query that uses IN or NOT IN slow?
>
> This is an issue with Firebird optimizer. In newer Firebird versions
>   the problem with IN is fixed, but the problem with NOT IN remains. In
>   any case, it is safe and often faster to use EXISTS and NOT EXISTS
>   instead. Each IN and NOT IN query can be rewritten to use EXISTS and
>   NOT EXISTS.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> select * from employee e
> where e.emp_no in (select s.emp_no from SALARY_HISTORY s);
>
> -- rewritten with EXISTS:
>
> select * from employee e
> where exists (select 1 from SALARY_HISTORY s where e.emp_no = s.emp_no);
> ```

Not sure the date on it, but I'm almost positive it predates 2.5 and I am certainly not seeing the same results it mentions in my testing (that it was fixed in later version, nor that EXISTS should work fine).

Comment: With a little testing, it look like those articles you read about optimization of `IN` where only talking about `IN` with a literal list, not a sub-query.

Comment: Other than my suggestion to switch to an inner join, I can only suggest that you file an improvement ticket in the Firebird tracker; it helps if you include a complete reproduction script (including an `execute block` or something to generate the test data). Make sure it is complete (eg the primary key definition on `detail`, etc).

Comment: i'd say, before putting to tracker one better to try first on FB 3.0.2 - maybe it is improved already

Comment: "Why does Firebird 2.5.5 and higher not use index" - basically here you say that FB versions BEFORE 2.5.5 did use that index. Which versions did used the index on that statement ?

Comment: what about join in select? `SELECT T.* FROM TEST T, (SELECT DISTINCT D.DETAILID FROM DETAIL D WHERE D.DETAILID BETWEEN 1 AND 100) D_SEL
WHERE T.DETAILID = D_SEL.DETAILID`

Comment: would your select PLANs improve if you uplift the `T.DETAILID BETWEEN 1 AND 100` condition to the outer-most WHERE ?  Also you can SPECIFY the plan for queries explicitly, though it is not suggested.

Comment: A somewhat outdated article written by core FB developers - www.translate.ru -> "computers dictionary" -> http://www.ibase.ru/dataaccesspaths/

Comment: "I created 10k records in each table and integer field numbered 1 to 10k." - does it mean that DETAILID field never repeats itself, and thus you get 100 rows from TEST table in this query?

Comment: @Arioch'The No, FB 3.0.2 behaves the same.

Comment: I have updated the post to answer most of the questions asked.  Thanks for the feedback thus far.